# Is it possible to route USB 2.0 using regular traces?

Tags: usb, differential, routing, trace

In the future I will be faced to design a system that includes USB 2.0 connectivity. I've seen that there are many trace calculators, but as far as I can see, they refer to microstrip lines.

So, is it possible to route using regular traces? Maybe if the distance is short enough. Do I need to add additional resistors to the lines?

Comment: In CPU of PC, the front usb panel is connected to motherboard by plain wires. Four separate pieces of wires. No transmission line, nothing. So it is possible for low speed applications.

Comment: @AJN Plain wires means no consideration for impedance matching at all.

Comment: @AJN That is not true. The cabling for USB data pins to front panel is a transmission line, they are usually a twisted differential pair inside the cable. Also the wiring on a motherboard is a differential pair.

Comment: I just checked my PC. It is an old school ribbon cable where we can pull the wires apart if we need to. The last one or two inches have been pulled apart to connect to the pcb on the front panel. It may be a **very shoddy work**, but I have never faced any issues with wireless keyboard dongles, USB drives, external hard drive, wire mouse, etc. That is what prompted my earlier comment. But I do agree with the motherboard side traces.

Comment: @AJN a ribbon cable can also be considered as transmission line as it can be engineered for certain impedance. Also, even if the insides of your PC are cheap and dubious, it does not mean that's how it is always done or how it should be done.

Comment: Which flavor of USB 2 do you use? Full Speed, High Speed?

Comment: @asdfex Full speed is more than enough.

Comment: A nice tutorial on USB PCB traces here:
https://training.ti.com/layout-basics-for-usb-designs Here's a calculator for sizing the PCB traces and spacing:
https://www.eeweb.com/tools/edge-coupled-microstrip-impedance/ Hope that helps someone!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on many factors, like what chip are you connecting to, and how long is the distance from connector to chip, and whether you want it to work reliably, or have to pass the compliance testing.

The resitors depend completely on the chip if it requires resistors or not. Some do, some don't.

The USB interface is a differential signal, so it requires a medium with defined differential impedance, to prevent signal reflections at discontinuities. Therefore it must be routed on PCB as a differential pair with defined impedance. I don't know what do you mean with regular traces, as any regular trace on a ground plane is a microstrip. It's just that the trace widths and distances on the ground plane are calculated so that the resulting impedance is suitable.

Comment: I've seen this definition: "Stripline is a transmission line trace surrounded by dielectric material suspended between two ground planes on internal layers of a PCB." By regular trace I mean a normal/usual differential PCB trace. So, according to you, I can use regular traces.

Comment: A trace with ground plane on only one side is `microstrip`, in between two ground planes, it's called `stripline`. And yes, it's just a normal PCB trace but with calculated properties and matched routing.

Comment: @awjlogan Thank you for the clarification.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get high speed operation then you will need to use controlled impedance tracking. These are 'ordinary' in the sense that they are still signal interfaces. They are not ordinary in the sense that they are more constrained than other routing.

Full speed (12 Mb) can use less rigorous layout.

USB 2 does *not* imply that high speed signalling (480 Mb) is available incidentally.

USB 2 can be quite brittle at high speed if not laid out properly.